# Why is my rewrite rule resulting in "400: Bad Request"?

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

I have these rewrite rules in my site configuration:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^app.php - [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php$0 [L]
```

The goal is that all requests should be appended to the front controller "app.php". The last line of the rules is causing my server to respond with "400: Bad Request" no matter what path I try, even an empty path. I have enabled the rewrite log and attempted two paths: "/" and "/login". This is what the log says:

```
(2) init rewrite engine with requested uri /
(3) applying pattern '^app.php' to uri '/'
(3) applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri '/'
(2) rewrite '/' -> 'app.php/'
(2) local path result: app.php/
(2) init rewrite engine with requested uri /login
(3) applying pattern '^app.php' to uri '/login'
(3) applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri '/login'
(2) rewrite '/login' -> 'app.php/login'
(2) local path result: app.php/login
```

According to the logs it should succeed. If I remove the last line of the rewrite rules and visit the URL "app.php/login" then it works as expected.

Does anybody have any idea why this isn't working?

---

*Note:* There are no errors in the error logs.
*Note:* The resulting paths ("app.php/", "app.php/login") work perfectly when the last rewrite rule is removed.

Comment: What is in your apache error log? Does using the URI app.php/login work if you don't have rewriting enabled?

Comment: @JennyD: I forgot to specify about the error logs, but I clearly state that the paths work perfectly when I remove the rewrite rule. Updated question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out. For some reason I had to append a "/" to the rewrite path:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /app.php$0 [L]
```

Otherwise, apparently, any path would rewrite to:

```
example.comapp.php/
```

I have another server with the same Apache version where this did not occur so I'm still confused, but at least it works.

Comment: On the other server, do you by any chance have a `RewriteBase` directive? Or is one of them having the rewrite in `httpd.conf` and the other in a `.htaccess` file? See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase for an explanation.

Comment: @JennyD: Yes, you are absolutely correct in both your questions. My other server has the rewrite rules in a htaccess file and also uses `RewriteBase /`. That explains it then?

Comment: Yep - `RewriteBase /` means that the `/` is automagically inserted at the start of the rewrite.