# HTTP 400 483 with Apache ProxyPassMatch and RewriteCond

Tags: reverse-proxy, php-fpm, apache2

I keep getting an error of:

```
apache_1_da0b6d97082f | 172.24.0.1 - - [16/Sep/2019:15:58:52 +0000] "GET /logi HTTP/1.1" 400 483 "-" "curl/7.64.0"
```

But I have no idea why? It seems the request does not get passed through to the php-fpm socket.

```
ServerName mainapp.local

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mainapp.local

    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/public/
    CustomLog /dev/stdout combined
    LogLevel debug

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L,QSA]

    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPassMatch "^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$"           "unix:/this/path/does/not/matter.sock|fcgi://localhost/var/www/html/public"

    <Directory "/var/www/html">
        Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +IncludesNOEXEC -MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
        DirectoryIndex index.php
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

It works correctly (HTTP 200) without the `Rewrite` directives - but obviously I do need this functionality.

---

If I enable `LogLevel debug rewrite:trace8`:

```
... mod_rewrite.c(483): [client 172.24.0.1:50934] 172.24.0.1 - - [localhost/sid#7f20f4ad15e8][rid#7f20f40e50a0/initial] init rewrite engine with requested uri /test
... mod_rewrite.c(483): [client 172.24.0.1:50934] 172.24.0.1 - - [localhost/sid#7f20f4ad15e8][rid#7f20f40e50a0/initial] applying pattern '(.+)' to uri '/test'
... mod_rewrite.c(483): [client 172.24.0.1:50934] 172.24.0.1 - - [localhost/sid#7f20f4ad15e8][rid#7f20f40e50a0/initial] RewriteCond: input='/test' pattern='!-f' => matched
... mod_rewrite.c(483): [client 172.24.0.1:50934] 172.24.0.1 - - [localhost/sid#7f20f4ad15e8][rid#7f20f40e50a0/initial] RewriteCond: input='/test' pattern='!-d' => matched
... mod_rewrite.c(483): [client 172.24.0.1:50934] 172.24.0.1 - - [localhost/sid#7f20f4ad15e8][rid#7f20f40e50a0/initial] rewrite '/test' -> 'index.php?p=/test'
... mod_rewrite.c(483): [client 172.24.0.1:50934] 172.24.0.1 - - [localhost/sid#7f20f4ad15e8][rid#7f20f40e50a0/initial] split uri=index.php?p=/test -> uri=index.php, args=p=/test
... mod_rewrite.c(483): [client 172.24.0.1:50934] 172.24.0.1 - - [localhost/sid#7f20f4ad15e8][rid#7f20f40e50a0/initial] local path result: index.php
```

---

Here is the `Dockerfile` I used to build the image:

```
# FROM debian:buster

FROM debian@sha256:903779f30a7ee46937bfb21406f125d5fdace4178074e1cc71c49039ebf7f48f

ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

RUN apt update
RUN apt install -y apache2 libapache2-mod-fcgid

COPY ./mainapp_vhost.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

RUN a2enmod actions proxy proxy_ajp proxy_http proxy_fcgi rewrite
RUN mkdir /var/lib/php-fcgi

RUN chmod 644 /var/log/apache2

ENV APACHE_UID 33
ENV APACHE_GID 33

RUN ln -sf /dev/stdout /var/log/apache2/access.log
RUN ln -sf /dev/stderr /var/log/apache2/error.log

RUN mkdir /var/www/html/public

RUN apachectl configtest

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/sbin/apache2ctl"]
CMD ["-D", "FOREGROUND"]
```

Comment: Check the Apache error log.

Comment: I did attach the appropriate out from the error/access log.

Comment: I see an access log entry, but the debug trace entries in your question don't correspond to it. Please look further.

Comment: Either my configuration is not logging the errors - or Apache isn't writing anything to the error log. Is there some way to verify?

Comment: Look for the `ErrorLog` directive in the Apache configuration and ensure that it does something sensible . Or at least you can find out what it was doing.

Comment: ```
root@304cf01845b4:/# grep 'Error' /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
# ErrorLog: The location of the error log file.
# If you do not specify an ErrorLog directive within a <VirtualHost>
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
```

Comment: So it sounds like it's ended up in a file somewhere in your container. The default directory being `/etc/httpd/logs`

Comment: To my understanding it's going to `/var/log/apache2/error.log` which I then point to the docker's /dev/stderr - so I don't think I'm dropping any errors here.

Comment: Well, something definitely got dropped. If you made a request and got a 400 Bad Request response from Apache, there will be a corresponding error log entry explaining why the error was returned. Try reproducing it. Of course, there won't be an error log entry if the 400 response came from your app, so you should consider that possibility as well.

Comment: I appreciate your suggestions - but I'm not sure how much further I could reproduce this. If you try build the docker image, and just send a request to that process - you should get exactly the same output as I do.

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs most probably due to a malformed URL - even though it reports just a vague `Bad Request` error.

---

It was probably the missing `/`....

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php [L,QSA]
```

Instead of

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L,QSA]
```

[Why is my rewrite rule resulting in "400: Bad Request"?](https://serverfault.com/questions/511599/why-is-my-rewrite-rule-resulting-in-400-bad-request)